# Understanding Classes and Methods in Python 3

Tags: python, class, function, methods, self

Alright, after viewing a lot of tutorial videos about classes i'm still having trouble understanding them for this assignment i have to do.

I need to write a program that essentially does high card, which means I need 2 cards to face off and one be the winner with suits and ranking.

2-14 being rank (11=jack, 12=queen, 13=king, 14=ace)

1-4 being suit(clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades)

this is what I have so far

```
    class Card:
        def __init__(self, inRank, inSuit):
        self.__rank = inRank
        self.__suit = inSuit
```

Could someone just point me in the right direction here? i'm drawing blanks on how to start this.

Comment: Write down, in pseudocode or english language, how you decide which of two cards is better. Then translate it into python.

Comment: As a side note, your indentation is not correct (unless its a mistake in the paste).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is fine, although I would remove the underscores in the attributes, since you have not implemented any methods for comparing the objects. I would define a `face_off` -function which takes in `card` objects as arguments and returns the winner. If I understand correctly, your simply compare the `rank` attribute of the two cards and return the higher. Then wrap the whole thing in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

You don't actually even need classes for this, the cards could be `dict` or `tuple`, however if you want a class then you could define [rich comparison methods](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) for your class so you could compare the objects instead of the attributes. You could then utilize the builtins of python and your `faceoff` could just return `max(card_object_one, card_object_two)`. This works with dicts and tuples by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick side note. Python [mangles class and instance variables](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) whose name begins with two underscores. I'd recommend using one underscore (or none at all) instead.

Getting back to your original question. My next step would be to create a method `faceoff` that accepts another card instance. This method could either return the winning card, or a boolean that lets you know if the caller has won.

For example:

```
def faceoff(self, other):
    # Compare self against other
    # ...

    # if self beats other
        return True
    return False
```